# How to avoid using harcoded SQL credentials

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a SQL database, and I am currently using hard-coded credentials in the PHP files. How can I ensure people cannot see these credentials?

I have seen people saying use a config file, but I do not know how to do that

The credentials are currently hard-coded to every PHP file that needs DB access.

Comment: you need a `REST` api

Comment: PHP code cannot be viewed with the web developer tools, if the web server is configured correctly for PHP. You can have the credentials in one PHP file if you use [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: You should use environment variables. In case of your script may be seen in public, the credentials are still hidden. https://dev.to/enygma/keeping-credentials-secure-in-php-1mgo

Comment: `I would like to know how i can make it so people cannnot see my credentials when viewing php files through web developer tools`...this should already be the case, unless your webserver is completely misconfigured. Have you observed this actually occuring?

Comment: `use a config file but i do not know how to do that`...it's just a text file, with stuff in it. e.g. you could store the data in JSON format, which is then easy to decode. Your application would then just need a function which loads the data from the file into some variables, so it can use them. Very similar to loading any stored data really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to write your database connection code once, in a separate PHP file:

`db.php`:

```
<?php

define("DBHOST", "localhost");
define("DBUSER", "myuser");
define("DBPASSWORD", "mypassword");
define("DBSCHEMA", "myschema");

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={DBHOST};dbname={DBSCHEMA}", DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);
```

Then in a given PHP script where you need the database, use `require()` so this file is loaded:

```
<?php

require('db.php');

$db->query(...any query you want...);
```

I showed the database credentials defined in `db.php` with PHP constants. You could alternatively store the credentials in a configuration file that is read to get those values.

`db.ini`:

```
DBHOST = localhost
DBUSER = myuser
DBPASSWORD = mypassword
DBSCHEMA = myschema
```

`db.php`:

```
<?php

$dbcfg = parse_ini_file('db.ini');

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbcfg['DBHOST']};dbname={$dbcfg['DBSCHEMA']}", $dbcfg['DBUSER'], $dbcfg['DBPASSWORD']);
```

No one should be able to read your PHP code files or configuration files. The http server should prevent this, by *running* PHP files instead of serving them up to be viewed. Http requests can view the result of the PHP script's output, but not the PHP code itself.

But http servers may become misconfigured, and accidentally serve PHP files. To reduce this risk, put most of your PHP code outside the http document root, so even if an http request could view PHP source files, they can't view files that are not served by the http server. Some of the PHP files must be reachable by http, but you can reference most of your code in other PHP files via the [include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Likewise the `db.ini` file should be outside the http document root, and referenced by the include_path.